# How to export data from excel to mysql by using php?

Tags: mysql, excel

The Code i tried is

```
$source = fopen('filename.csv', 'r') or die("Problem open file");
    while (($data = fgetcsv($source, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
    {
        $name = $data[0];
       `$mobile = $data[1];


        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`name`,`mobile`) VALUES ('".$name."','".$mobile ."') ");


    }
    fclose($source);
```

but it takes only last record...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way to do it, using PHP `fgetcsv()` and `mysqli()`:

**1. Connect to mysqli:**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
```

**2. Open your CSV file:**

```
$source = fopen('filename.csv', 'r') or die("Problem open file");
```

**3. With a loop read the CSV and put your inserts queries in a variable:**

```
$query="";
do { 
    if ($fields[0]) { 
        $query.="INSERT INTO `table_name` (`name`, `mobile`) VALUES 
            ( 
                '".addslashes($fields[0])."', 
                '".addslashes($fields[1])."' 
            ) 
        ;"; 
    } 
} while ($fields = fgetcsv($source,1000,",","'"));
```

**4. Excute your query and close mysqli:**

```
if($mysqli->multi_query($query)) echo "Data successfuly added";
$mysqli->close();
```

[fgetcsv documentation](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.fgetcsv.php).

[Myqli multiquery documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add the whole file using MySQL rather than breaking it up by line?   Something like

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'filename.csv' INTO TABLE table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

or if you've got specific columns that need to go into specific fields,

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'filename.csv' INTO TABLE table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' (@c1, @c2) 
set name = @c1, mobile = @c2;
```